# Array perdendo campo após sair do foreach

Tags: php

Tenho um array de objeto quero adicionar um campo em cada item faço um foreach para isso, mas o campo some após sair do loop

```
foreach ($this->questions as $question) {
           var_dump($question); // aqui é apresentado o array no estado comum
           $question['survey_id'] = $survey_id;
           var_dump($question); // após a adesão de um novo campo o array se modifica mostrando o campo adicionado
}
// mas aqui ele volta para seu estado natural
var_dump($this->questions);
```

Por que acontece isso?

Comment: `$question` é diferente de `$questions`. Para melhor compreensão do problema, especifique quais os valores presentes em `$questions` e tipo de valor que queres adicionar nela.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Em primeiro lugar a variável $question é apenas temporária e não tem ligação nenhuma com a variável $questions. Você poderia tentar passar ela como referencia, acredito que neste caso você consiga fazer o que deseja.

```
foreach ($this->questions as &$question) {

       $question['survey_id'] = $survey_id;

}

var_dump($this->questions);
```

Veja se desta maneira até as sua necessidade.

Comment: Uau funcionou! então é como se fosse um ponteiro

Comment: Fazendo uma analogia, seria isto mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

tente assim:

```
foreach ($this->questions as $question) {
           var_dump($question); // aqui é apresentado o array no estado comum
           $this->questions['survey_id'] = $survey_id;
           var_dump($question); // após a adesão de um novo campo o array se modifica mostrando o campo adicionado
}
// mas aqui ele volta para seu estado natural
var_dump($this->questions);


ou


foreach ($this->questions as $question) {
           var_dump($question); // aqui é apresentado o array no estado comum
           $this->questions['survey_id'] = $survey_id;
           var_dump($question); // após a adesão de um novo campo o array se modifica mostrando o campo adicionado
}
// mas aqui ele volta para seu estado natural
var_dump($question);
```

Comment: `$question` não está definida fora do bloco `foreach`